# .net core authentication provider for WSO2

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, wso2

Is there any plan (or if it already exists?) for releasing OAuth provider for .net core?

Here you can see the providers for other vendors: 
https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers

Regards, 
Sanjay